# How do I draw a pie chart

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gradient

I'm bit new for designing. I'm trying to draw a pie chart for a dashboard design. I tried editing gradients but could located the positions correctly.If I am to use 3 colours for the pie chart how can I locate the colours. I am using photoshop cc 2015.

[image: tried with gradents]

I want the pie chart to look like this 
[image: <image from google>]

Comment: Perhaps this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=df_bbcgDQDc) can help

Comment: The pie chart in your example is not made with a gradient.

Comment: You took a task which takes in Illustrator few minutes and the result can be cutted and pasted into as high resolution image in Photoshop as needed, if it for some reason must be in Photoshop. Illustrator has proper tools for generating most common business graphs from numbers. The hole in the middle can be made afterwards to right size. Drawing it from scratch in Illustrator without the graph tool also is a minor task.

Comment: (continued) For fast results you can use an online graph generator. If screen resolution image is ok, try for ex. https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/pie-chart.html. You must cut the hole to the pie by yourself.

Comment: I would use Excel or Open office to do that, and export it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the comments, Photoshop is not the best program to make this kind of graphics.

But the way to do it is with shapes and a gradient angled overlay effect applied to the layer .

[image: ANGLE GRADIENT]

[image: Animation]

*<sub>Sorry for the gif quality, 2mb maximum size</sub>*

Comment: Your gif will be lighter if you do not move the windows.

Comment: Thank-you very much. gif made it easy to understand.

Comment: @KittyJ, don't use gradients to make pie charts or donut charts. There is no need to do that. PS has a pen tool just like Illustrator... I'd rather use that + a clipping mask.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this by using the ellipse tool and adding an interior stroke (recommend to make large 70pts) and select a color.Then duplicate the layer, change the color & rasterize the layer. Then use marquee tool or eraser tool to delete the parts of the circle you need to remove, revealing the tri-colored graph.

Comment: It's better to use shapes and paths instead, there's no need to rasterize anything. Or use Illustrator as mentioned in another answer.